# Reflect a point without matrix math

Tags: matrices, functions, linear-transformations, transformation, desmos

I'm working on writing some utility functions for the Desmos Art Contest.
So far, I have

Rotation:
$
R_{otate}(x,\space y,\space\theta\,\space p_x,\space p_y)=((x-p_x)\cos\theta-(y-p_y)\sin\theta+p_x,\space(y-p_y)\sin\theta+(x-p_y)\cos\theta+p_y)
$

Transformation:
$
T_{ransform}(x,y,i_x,i_y)=({x+i_x},\space{y+i_y})
$

For my reflection, I want it to have a signature similar to
$$
\Large f\normalsize\Bigg(\Big[\begin{smallmatrix}\Large x\\\Large y\end{smallmatrix}\Big]\huge_,\normalsize\bigg[\begin{smallmatrix}\Large l_{x1}&&\Large l_{x2}\\\Large l_{y1}&&\Large l_{y2}\end{smallmatrix}\bigg]\Bigg)\rightarrow\bigg[\begin{smallmatrix}\Large x\vphantom{2_x}\prime\\\Large y\prime\end{smallmatrix}\bigg]
$$
But I cannot use matrices in the Desmos Graphing Calculator. Thus, I plan on just having each element of the matrices just be their own parameter (no, I'm not writing it in $\small\LaTeX$. I am innable). But, all ways to calculate it as far as I've seen use matrix math. How can I implement a reflection without them?

Variables $l_{x1}$, $l_{x2}$, $l_{y1}$, and $l_{y2}$ correspond to points on the line of reflection. As in, they correspond to a line formed by the equation 
$y-l_{x1}=\underbrace{\frac{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}}_{\text{slope}\space m}\large(x-l_{y1})$

Comment: Strange question. Matrices have been introduced to facilitate some algebraic operation which can be still expressed without using matrices...

Comment: @the_candyman I haven't learned about matrices, so I don't know how I could represent these then.

Comment: @CATboardBETA Could you explain what details you are looking for in an answer? In what way are either of the answers below insufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use vector algebra, which is not too different from standard algebra. This is as simple and matrix-free as it can get (using the definition $y=mx + a$ is just ugly in my opinion). The derivation also requires basic calculus. Let $L$ be a line, and $\mathbf{q} = (q_1, q_2)$ be a point. The line can be described using the parametric equation
$$
L(t) = \mathbf{v}t + \mathbf{a} = (v_1t + a_1, v_2t + a_2),
$$
where $\mathbf{v}=(v_1, v_2)$ is a direction vector, and $\mathbf{a}=(a_1, a_2)$ is a point on $L$.

Then the reflection $\mathbf{q}^*$ of $\mathbf{q}$ over $L$ is simply
$$
\mathbf{q}^*= 2(\mathbf{v}t^* + \mathbf{a}) - \mathbf{q} = (2(v_1t^* + a_1) - q_1, 2(v_2t^* + a_2) - q_2),\label{eq:1}\tag{1}
$$
where $$t^* = \frac{q_1v_1 + q_2v_2 - a_1v_1 - a_2v_2}{v_1^2 + v_2^2}.$$

Now plug $a_1=l_{x1},a_2 = l_{x2},v_1 = l_{x2}-l_{x1}$, $v_2 = l_{y2}-l_{y1}$, and the rest is just algebra. The parametric equation of the line is particularly convenient, because it allows us to define a line from two points on the line.

**Derivation**:
Let $\mathbf{u}=(u_1, u_2)$ be a point on $L$ that minimizes the distance between $\mathbf{q}$ and $L$, i.e. we want to find a $\mathbf{u} = L(t^*)$ that minimizes $$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2}\lVert L(t) - \mathbf{q}\rVert^2 =
\frac{1}{2}\left\{(v_1t + a_1 - q_1)^2 + (v_2t + a_2 - q_2)^2\right\}.
$$
Then the reflection $\mathbf{q}^*$ is simply $\mathbf{q}^* = \mathbf{q} + 2(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{q}) = 2\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{q} = (2u_1 - q_1, 2u_2 - q_2)$, see figure below (blue arrow is $2(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{q})$)[[image: Reflection of a point <span class=]$\mathbf{q} across a line $L$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZEy6.png)

Now, using calculus, we know that $f'(t^*) = 0$, so
$$f'(t^*) = (v_1t^* + a_1 - q_1)v_1 + (v_2t^* + a_2 - q_2)v_2 = 0,$$
or
$$ t^* = \frac{(a_1 - q_1)v_1 + (a_2 - q_2)v_2}{v_1^2 + v_2^2}. $$
Finally, $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{v}t^* + \mathbf{a} = (v_1t^* + a_1, v_2t^* + a_2)$, leading to \ref{eq:1} after putting everything together.

Note that $\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{q}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}$, i.e.
$$ (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{q})\cdot \mathbf{v} = (u_1 - q_1)v_1 + (u_2 - q_2)v_2 = (v_1t^* + a_1 - q_1)v_1 + (v_2t^* + a_2 - q_2)v_2 = f'(t^*) = 0. $$

Comment: To answer your question, no, not at all. I'll look into them for this answer though.

Comment: @CATboardBETA It's okay, it's just symbols at this point, and a vector is just a list of numbers for this case. All you need to know is vector addition and scalar multiplication, used in the equation for $\mathbf{q}^*$.

Comment: If my math is correct, then this only works for a line that passes through the origin. Is this true?

Comment: No, it works for any line.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix-less way to go about it is this: Given a line $y = m x + b$, lines perpendicular to it have slope $-1/m$ (let's avoid horizontal lines, they're easier to work with for these purposes anyhow).

Hence if we have a point $P = (u, v)$ somewhere, and we want to reflect it through the aforementioned line, we know the reflection must lie on the line $y - v = -1/m (x - u)$, and now it is just a matter of figuring out what the $x$-coordinate of the reflection is.

One way to do this is working out the $x$-coordinate where the two lines intersect, by setting
$$ m x + b = -\frac{1}{m} (x - u) + v, $$
and on solving for $x$ we get
$$ x = \frac{u/m + v - b}{m + 1/m}. $$
Now the *difference* between this $x$-coordinate and $u$ is how "far" we travel (in the $x$-direction) to get from $P = (u, v)$ to the point of intersection. I'll call this value $t$.
Travel twice as far and we are at the point of reflection.

Hence the $x$-coordinate of the point of reflection is $u + 2(t - u)$, and plugging this into the the equation for the perpendicular line we get
$$ Q = \Bigl( u + 2(t - u), -\frac{1}{m}( u + 2(t - u) - u ) + v \Bigr) $$
for the point of reflection.

To turn this into a function of parameters $l_{x_1}, l_{x_2}, l_{y_1}, l_{y_2}$ defining points on the original line $y = m x + b$, simply work out the slope $m$ and the $y$-intercept $b$ in terms of them.

A (quickly thrown together) example Desmos sketch of this is here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lecdqrklvc

---

**Edit:** If you go through the work of rewriting $Q$ in terms of $l_{x_1}, l_{x_2}, l_{y_1}, l_{y_2}$, you get this hideous expression:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(&x,y,l_{x1},l_{x2},l_{y1},l_{y2})= \\ &\left(2\frac{x\frac{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}+y+\frac{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}\ l_{x1}-l_{y1}}{\frac{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}+\frac{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}}-x,-2\frac{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}\left(\frac{x\frac{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}+y+\frac{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}\ l_{x1}-l_{y1}}{\frac{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}+\frac{l_{x2}-l_{x1}}{l_{y2}-l_{y1}}}-x\right)+y\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Again I've made a quick Desmos sketch of this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kelcvp7dxl

Comment: To make this into a single function taking the point you want to reflect and the points on the line of reflection as input, simply start with the final expression for $Q$ and substitute $t$, $m$, $b$, etc., backwards. It'll be a huge, unpleasant looking mess, but such is life sometimes.